# CCApplication::getCurrentLanguage() get null on cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm working on Linux actually, but I use Mac too.

I'm trying to add multi language support to my game, and I'm going to use different XML with tags.

When I use `ccLanguageType _myLanguage = CCApplication::getCurrentLanguage()` get null, signal 11 exception.

I have used `getCurrentLanguageJNI()`  too but it did't work.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use CCApplication::sharedApplication().getCurrentLanguage();

Comment: Deprecated in version 3.7.
Use getInstance() instead